# How to make the DHT11 sensor work with the sysfs gpio manipulation method?

Tags: gpio, c

So i am trying to connect a DHT11 sensor to my Raspberry Pi 2.
 My wiring is correct, since i got it working with the wiringPi library.
 Since i don't want to use someone else's library I've created my own([click to see](https://github.com/AleksandarDashov/Raspberry-Pi-2/tree/master/GPIO_Controller)), that simply reads and writes data to the /sys/class/gpio directory, but i can't get the DHT11 sensor working.

Here is the code:

```
#include <wiringPi.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include "GPIO_Controller.h"

#define MAXTIMINGS 85

int dht11_dat[5] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

void read_dht11_dat()
{
    uint8_t laststate       = 1;
    uint8_t counter         = 0;
    uint8_t j               = 0, i;
    float   f; /* fahrenheit */

    dht11_dat[0] = dht11_dat[1] = dht11_dat[2] = dht11_dat[3] = dht11_dat[4] = 0;


    GPIO_Controller pin4;
    pin4.GPIO_Export(4);

    pin4.GPIO_Direction("out");

    /* pull pin down for 18 milliseconds */
    //      pinMode( 7, OUTPUT );
    pin4.GPIO_Value(0);//   digitalWrite( 7, LOW );
    delay( 18 );
    /* then pull it up for 40 microseconds */
    pin4.GPIO_Value(1);     //digitalWrite(7, HIGH );
    delayMicroseconds( 40 );
    /* prepare to read the pin */
    pin4.GPIO_Direction("in");//    pinMode( 7, INPUT );

    /* detect change and read data */
    for ( i = 0; i < MAXTIMINGS; i++ )
    {
            counter = 0;
            int val = pin4.getGPIO_Value();
            //              print   f("Val: %d", val);
            while ( val/*digitalRead(7)*/ == laststate )
            {
                    counter++;
                    delayMicroseconds( 1 );
                    if ( counter == 255 )
                    {
                            break;
                    }
            }
            int omg = pin4.getGPIO_Value();
            laststate =omg;/*digitalRead( 7 );*/
            if ( counter == 255 )
                    break;

            /* ignore first 3 transitions */
            if ( (i >= 4) && (i % 2 == 0) )
            {
                    /* shove each bit into the storage bytes */
                    dht11_dat[j / 8] <<= 1;
                    if ( counter > 16 )
                            dht11_dat[j / 8] |= 1;
                    j++;
            }
    }

    /*
     * check we read 40 bits (8bit x 5 ) + verify checksum in the last byte
     * print it out if data is good
     */
    if ( (j >= 40) &&  (dht11_dat[4] == ( (dht11_dat[0] + dht11_dat[1] + dht11_dat[2] + dht11_dat[3]) & 0xFF) ) )
    {
            f = dht11_dat[2] * 9. / 5. + 32;
            printf( "Humidity = %d.%d %% Temperature = %d.%d *C (%.1f *F)\n",
                    dht11_dat[0], dht11_dat[1], dht11_dat[2], dht11_dat[3], f );
    }else  {
            printf( "Data not good, skip\n" );
    }



    }

    int main()
    {

        printf( "Raspberry Pi wiringPi DHT11 Temperature test program\n"        );

        if ( wiringPiSetup() == -1 )
           exit( 1 );

        while ( 1 )
        {
            read_dht11_dat();
            delay( 1000 ); /* wait 1sec to refresh */
        }
        return 0;

    }
```

Here i substituted the wiringPi functions with my own, but i am getting "data not good" on every loop cycle.
I've searched the web and i didn't find someone that got it working with the sysfs method.

Any idea why the DHT11 sensor is not working with the sysfs method?

Comment: I expect the timings are too tight.  From memory you need to distinguish gaps in the 80-120µs region.  Most of the Pi implementations would be doing busy spins to find the bit timings, that's why most of the implementations are pretty poor, getting somewhere in the region of a good read in every two or three attempts.

Comment: Yes, but the timing works great with the wiringPi functions, and when i put my own functions which only manipulates the pins input or output, HIGH(1) or LOW(0) it doesn't  get the data right. That's why i assume the problem is in my own functions that only manipulates the gpio pins.
And by the way, i would be happy if i get 1 good read out of 10...

Comment: I guess the SYS FS interface is taking too long to change the GPIO mode from output to input.

Comment: Thank you, your well educated guess got me into the right direction i guess. Will post a solution if i get one!

Comment: My [piscope](http://abyz.co.uk/rpi/pigpio/piscope.html) will let you view the DHT11 signals.  The front-end (display)  will work on a Pi but it works better if you run the front-end on a more powerful Linux machine.